# useNavigate not working with button click ("Converting circular structure to JSON" error)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, circular-reference, nested-routes

I'm trying to create a desktop app using the electron-react boilerplate on GitHub and at the moment, I'm trying to create routes for the multiple pages I intend to use for the app. I looked up how to do so, and I saw that I could use `useNavigate()`, `onClick` for the button, and `Routes`, `Router`, and `Route` from React. However, it isn't working.

I've attempted nesting the `Route` components so that the home page has the welcome page appended to it, which could get replaced with the login page on the button click, but that didn't work. Then, I tried listing the `Route` components instead, and that didn't work either. I tried looking up other posts about this issue, but nothing they had helped. I also tried switching out the `useNavigate` import to originate from `react-router` instead of `react-router-dom`, but that didn't work either.

Here is the code I've been working with so far:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';

import TitleBar from './COMPONENTS/title_bar.js'
import perspective_grid from '../../assets/images/perspective_grid.jpg'
import './App.css'
import './CSS/Home.css'

// grid background with overlaying gradient
function Background() {
  return (
    <div id = "background">
      <img className = "prevent-select prevent-drag absolute" id = "perspective-grid" src={perspective_grid}></img>
    </div>
  )
}

// welcome page (with login and signup buttons)
function Welcome() {

  let navigate = useNavigate('/login')
  return (
    <div id = "welcome">
      <h1 className = "prevent-select title">WTBDSB</h1>
      <p  id = "subtitle"><i><b>w</b>ants <b>t</b>o <b>b</b>e <b>d</b>esmos <b>s</b>o <b>b</b>ad</i></p>

      <button className = "btn prevent-drag" id = "login" onClick={navigate}>log in</button>
      <button className = "btn prevent-drag" id = "signup">sign up</button>

    </div>
  )
}

// login page
function Login() {
  return (
    <div id = "LOGIN">testtesttest</div>
  )
}

// signup page
function Signup() {
  return (
    <div id = "SIGNUP"></div>
  )
}

// full routing for the above pages.
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<>
          <TitleBar />
          <Background />
          <Welcome />
        </>} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />  

      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

And here is the error I'm getting (after I'm clicking the "log in" button):

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated - this is my first time working with Routes in React, and I'd love to be able to get this working so I can make more progress.

Comment: not sure if this is the underlying issue but one thing I noticed is that you assigned the route path on `useNavigate` as opposed to on `navigate`. For example, `const navigate = useNavigate()` and then in your `onClick` you would use `navigate` as such `onClick={() => navigate("/login")`. Here's their documentation: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Comment: @heyitsjhu  you are right. OP is trying to pass html event to navigate by accident

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to get it working earlier today! Below's the updated code. I used `const navigate = useNavigate()`, called navigate inside of a function, `handleClick()`, which was used as the `onClick` attribute for the login button. Then, I listed the routes (no nesting).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useNavigate, redirect } from 'react-router';

import TitleBar from './COMPONENTS/title_bar.js'
import perspective_grid from '../../assets/images/perspective_grid.jpg'
import './App.css'
import './CSS/Home.css'

// grid background with overlaying gradient
function Background() {
  return (
    <div id = "background">
      <img className = "prevent-select prevent-drag absolute" id = "perspective-grid" src={perspective_grid}></img>
    </div>
  )
}

// welcome page (with login and signup buttons)
function Welcome() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/login");
  }

  return (
    <div id = "welcome">
      <h1 className = "prevent-select title">WTBDSB</h1>
      <p id = "subtitle"><i><b>w</b>ants <b>t</b>o <b>b</b>e <b>d</b>esmos <b>s</b>o <b>b</b>ad</i></p>

      <button className = "btn prevent-drag" id = "login" onClick={handleClick}>log in</button>
      <button className = "btn prevent-drag" id = "signup">sign up</button>
    </div>
  )
}

// login page
function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleClick() {
    navigate("/");
  }

  return (
    <div id = "LOGIN">
      <button className = "btn prevent-drag" id = "signup" onClick={handleClick}>go back</button>
    </div>
  )
}

// signup page
function Signup() {
  return (
    <div id = "SIGNUP"></div>
  )
}

// full routing for the above pages.
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <TitleBar />
      <Background />
      <Router>
        <Routes>

          <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />  

        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}
```